# Where is the Crashlytics log file located for the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: android, firebase, logging, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

For the previous Crashlytics SDK (Fabric) the file location of the logging was:

```
On Linux / Windows: /.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
On Mac: ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
```

Since I started using the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK nothing is getting logged there anymore. I tried to search for other locations the file could be, but I couldn't find anything at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebaser here -

There is indeed no longer a crashlytics.log file. That information still exists if you invoke your symbol upload task with `--debug.` So if you have native symbol file upload enabled in Gradle, that may look like (all on Mac):

`./gradlew app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug --debug`

or

`./gradlew app:assembleDebug --console=plain --debug`

You may also see a lot of output irrelevant to Crashlytics. However your command looks, you may want to pipe a filter:

`./gradlew ... | grep "[com.google.firebase.crashlytics]"`

Finally, it can be inconvenient to be looking at the terminal or the logcat in Android Studio, so you may want to just save that output to a file:

`./gradlew ... > crashlyticslog.txt`

Comment: is there any way to recover files from my android app? i have set "setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)" so the logs are inside my app and I would like to understand how to retrieve them before sending to crashlytics server